# Wordpress custom do_parse_request always returns 404

Tags: php, wordpress, response-headers

So I created my own special `do_parse_request` filter and it works fantastically. Intercepts the right requests to return the correct content, and other request continue on their normal WordPressy ways. Basically I'm hijacking certain URLs to do some custom stuff outside normal WordPress  routing.

Except... The response is always a 404 despite being the correct content.

Is there something I'm missing that needs to be set in WordPress if the regular request isn't completed?

```
add_filter('do_parse_request', function($do_parse, $wp) {
    //... bunch of code to dynamically determine 
    //if a page belongs to custom source, which works
    if ($ismypage){
        remove_action('template_redirect', 'redirect_canonical');
        $wp->query_vars['post_type'] = 'my_post_type';
        $wp->query_vars['name'] = $mypagename;
        return false;
        //always a 404, even though I get expected content...
    } 
    return $do_parse;
}
```

---

**Tried:**

Poking around a bit, looked at WP_REST_Response right before the return false. Getting:

```
        $testResponse = new WP_REST_Response();
        var_dump($testResponse->get_headers());
        //empty array
        var_dump($testResponse->get_status());
        //int 200
```

Digging around more on the web revealed a literal `status_header` method. Even tried the `header("HTTP/1.1 200 Success")`

```
        //... right before return false
        status_header(200);
        //still gets 404 on the page, still gets correct content
        header("HTTP/1.1 200 Success");
        //same issue
```

I'm starting to think this isn't the cause of my issue...

Answer (score 0):

So uh... this worked. Not 1000% sure why, other than this must be getting called after something else determines that this is a 404. So a better answer is appreciated, but this at least overcomes the 404 response...

```
//right before return false in my do_parse_request filter
do_action( 'template_redirect' );
```

Then also add a template redirect filter and just set this to to 200:

```
add_filter("template_redirect", function(){
    status_header(200);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

this is probably a result of wordpress not stopping its default processing and since your URL most likely was not a page, a taxonomy or any other wordpress content it could not parse it and issued a 404.

This solved in 6.0 by ignoring default processing when the filter is being used (just from reading the documentation, didn't try it myself yet), and for earlier version you most likely needed to issue the 200 code "manually" although not sure if where you have done it is the best place.